# How to load in data and insert data together with a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to load in data first and then insert data into the same table.

I use a stored procedure to load in the data (I'm using SQL Server):

```
    @employeeid int,
    @thequestion varchar (220) output
)
as
begin
    begin transaction

    select @thequestion = thequestion
    from question q
    join contentment c on q.questionid= c.questionid
    where c.employeeid = @employeeid

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin 
        rollback
        raiserror ('You don't have question to answer', 16, 1)
        return
    end

    commit
end
```

Then the user can add data to the table contentment. He only can add a score and a comment

`Contentment` table:

```
employeeid,
questionid,
date,
score,
comment
```

I using this stored procedure:

```
(@score int,
 @comment varchar(50),
 @date date
)
as
begin
    begin transaction

        insert into contentment (date, score, comment)
        values (@date, @score, @comment)

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin 
            rollback
            raiserror ('-some error-', 16, 1)
            return
        end

  commit
end
```

The problem is that in the second stored procedure `questionid` and `employeeid` should not be inserted, it is already inserted, to link a `employeeid` to a `questionid`. But when I want to add a `score` and `comment` to this, I get an error that `questionid` and `employeeid` need to be inserted (otherwise it has value `NULL`). Also the problem is that my second stored procedure doesn't know which question belongs to the `questionid`/`employeeid`. I hope someone understand this, I know it is a bit weird.

Comment: Are these SPs being called from code? (If so, tag a language.) In my experience, theres.no point putting transactions around atomic statements (which have implicit transactions) - transactions can be used in the calling code to group different units of work. Raising errors is similar - the calling code can determine what happened, and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was busy travelling.

I tried creating 2nd procedure as follows.

Here I have created employeeid and questionid as 2 variables which we will passs while executing this stored procedure:

```
create procedure Proc2
```

(
@employeeid int
,@questionid int
,@score int
,@comment varchar(50)
,@date date
)
as
    begin
        begin transaction
            insert  into contentment (date, score, comment)
            select @date = date, @score = score, @comment = comment
            where employeeid = @employeeid and questionid = @questionid

```
    if @@ERROR <> 0

    begin 
        rollback
        raiserror ('-some error-', 16, 1)
        return
    end
```

end transaction
  commit
end

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: What I meant was you can have a function/stored procedure which takes the questionid/employeeid as input parameters. These input parameters can then be passed in the insert statement in WHERE clause, thereby avoiding NULL values for questionid/employeeid, also these 2 things will not be inserted again rather they will be used as conditions.

Comment: Could you maybe show me how you will do this? Thanks.